# Run Python Tkinter UI in non-main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a python 2.7 application which is generally just a console application and never needs a UI. But I'm trying to build a module for it that will pop up a super simple GUI. Basically, the code normally interfaces with various varieties of LED strips through separate, loadable, LED driver modules. These strips are the usual interface. What I want to do, is create a "dummy driver" for testing purposes that doesn't require that you have the LED hardware actually setup. Instead it would present a GUI that shows an drawn representation of the LED strip and a couple controls to handle animation flow for testing.

Tkinter seemed like a good idea at first since it was built into all python installs, however I don't want to re-architect my whole system just so Tkinter can be the main thread. Preferably, the UI would run in a separate thread (or maybe separate process altogether) and just receive a few update commands from the main thread that's running the animation and pushing data out to this dummy LED strip.

Is this even possible? Would there be a better solution than Tkinter for the UI (would have to run on any python capable OS).

Comment: use multiprocessing/threading to launch the GUI in a separate thread. Otherwise, try pygame : it is more suited for 2D animations.